# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat ... .steampath

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, visual-studio-code

I am trying to start the development server on a React project that I have not worked on for a long time. Upon running `npm install` and `npm start` I received the title error message.  
I tried manually updating and then downgrading the Node-sass but I am still getting the same error no matter what I do.
Here is the full error message I am getting.

```
Failed to compile.

./src/App.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-6-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--5-oneOf-6-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-6-4!./src/App.scss)
Error: Node Sass version 5.0.0 is incompatible with ^4.0.0.
/home/dylan/Desktop/Werk/Professional stuff/SkylimitHost/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js:19
  throw err;
  ^

[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/dylan/.steampath'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'stat',
  path: '/home/dylan/.steampath'
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! cleanapp@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the cleanapp@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/dylan/.npm/_logs/2020-11-23T05_19_03_778Z-debug.log
```

And here is the complete log

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   '/home/dylan/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.0/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/home/dylan/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.0/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.8
3 info using node@v14.15.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle cleanapp@0.1.0~prestart: cleanapp@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle cleanapp@0.1.0~start: cleanapp@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle cleanapp@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle cleanapp@0.1.0~start: PATH: /home/dylan/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/dylan/Desktop/Werk/Professional stuff/SkylimitHost/node_modules/.bin:/home/dylan/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
9 verbose lifecycle cleanapp@0.1.0~start: CWD: /home/dylan/Desktop/Werk/Professional stuff/SkylimitHost
10 silly lifecycle cleanapp@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'react-scripts start' ]
11 silly lifecycle cleanapp@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle cleanapp@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: cleanapp@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/home/dylan/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/dylan/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
14 verbose pkgid cleanapp@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd /home/dylan/Desktop/Werk/Professional stuff/SkylimitHost
16 verbose Linux 5.4.0-53-generic
17 verbose argv "/home/dylan/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.0/bin/node" "/home/dylan/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.0/bin/npm" "start"
18 verbose node v14.15.0
19 verbose npm  v6.14.8
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error cleanapp@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the cleanapp@0.1.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I don't understand why my server won't start, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: My co-worker had the same problem but different files showed up in the error for each of us. Mine was `.steampath` and his was `libpng12.so.o`.
imstupidpleasehelp's solution solved it.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I've found out the solution. This error is just a fancy/convoluted missing dependencies message. If you install all the dependencies the project needs (some might not be in the package.json file) it should work correctly.

Comment: I'm using `react-scripts@4.0.2` and I noticed that I can see which dependencies I forgot to install by looking at the import errors which show up for a fraction of a second just before the console clears and this error is shown

Comment: I had to screen-record the CLI logs and then watch in slow-motion to catch the module not found error and the names of missing modules, lol. Also, another way to do so is by installing all the packages again and watch for logs that say `unmet peer dependency` and then install those.

Comment: Thanks to this answer as well as the comments, I was able to run `yarn start > output.txt` which dumps the error message (the missing modules) to the file `output.txt`. This is such strange behavior and the fact that it's calling out `.steampath` specifically made me wonder if there was malware in my node_modules...

Comment: I assumed that material icons was part of material core, and got this error on importing icons. Once I did npm install of the icons, error went away. Just thought it would be helpful to give an example of how one might trigger this error.

Comment: This helped me, also @OozeMeister comment, thanks, in my case it was `@date-io/moment`

Comment: I found a quick workaround to the error clearing is piping yarn through `less`. (e.g. `yarn start | less`)

Answer (score 20):

If you are in a hurry! And don't have time to know why this is happening! you can **move and scroll directly** to "**How to resolve it (an elegant way)?**" section bellow (it's at the end)! I'm showing a strong efficient and clean solution!

## What is the problem ?

The whole problem is a **missing dependency**! That can be a js module or a file! Like a font file or something else like asset probably!

```cpp
And to note: A good error message is being cleaned! Recompiling!
And then the problem belloww is reached and you get the error!
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Then the error comes after! We can see a missing font in my case!

**But Why and how we are getting this error ?**

A **broken symlink** that reside in the home directory! That got checked by the **react-scripts start**, running process! And because it's broken the access throw a `is no file or directory` error.

In our case it was `.steampath`! Check the details on the next section (**what is steampath**)

To make it fun and confirm! I created a **broken symlink** with my name! Following the alphatbetical order! It will be processed first!

[image]

[image]

[image]

And yup! Here now! We have `.allalBrokenLink`! And not `.steampath`! A quick solution would be to remove the **broken symlink**! But this is not a good solution! the borken `.steampath` have it's purpose! If you are using steam game platofrm! If you don't! You can remove the file without worry!

Otherwise the solution is pretty simple and efficient! **Run in javascript debug terminal! And set a breakpoint where the error come! So it will pause automatically! And will get to see the problem easily and simply**! See this in the **How to resolve it (an elegant way)?** section!

**Why the home directory was checked ?**

The first thing to say! It's **not due to the nodejs module resolution algorithm**! **Again not due to the module resolution algorithm**!

**why!?**

Because the module resolution! When it comes to the module! And in the case where it need to go backward! It Go backward up to the file system root! And **each time** **checking** against **node_modules** folder!
So if it reach up to `/home/`! it will directly check against `/home/node_modules`! if there is! if not it go to `/node_modules`! And you can see how it will not check all files in a directory! And so **not cause the broken symlink problem**. Which is caused because something is iterating through all the files and checking them! It's not the case here!

The algorithm in such case, in extra to that, it check the [following](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_the_global_folders)

> Additionally, Node.js will search in the following list of GLOBAL_FOLDERS:
> 1: $HOME/.node_modules
> 2: $HOME/.node_libraries
> 3: $PREFIX/lib/node

That can be illustrated here! I accessed paths while debugging:

[image]

You can see how it go backward!

The algorithm is clear! You can check it here ([ref1](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together), [ref2](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders)!

And in the typescript doc [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#how-nodejs-resolves-modules)

Also we can verify it too ourselves!

First through accessing `module.paths` as like bellow:

[image]

I made a test! A simple testing project! Where i imported just a random name! You'll get a **clean `not found module` error!** Know that i tested in the same environment where i get the error bellow!

[image]

And you can check the error type!

**Yup we didn't mention the problem! Then what is it ??**

Babel for example was known for something similar! Where it looks for `.babelrc` config. However like node modules resolution, it go backward and checking for `.babelrc` specifically! And any resolution that have a lockup for a specific thing! Or within a specific thing! Will directly check for the thing! **Why check anything else!?** Given all that i doubt it would be something between babel, webpack and react-scripts details or config! And most probably some loader or plugin thing! I tried to debug manually! It was time consuming! I moved to automate the detection through the chrome devtools protocol! I'll update this section as soon as i get it!

### What is steampath

A file created by the **Game steam platform**.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1103540/why-is-there-a-steampath-in-my-home-directory

> This is a known Steam issue: the symlink is created and is intentionally broken for compatibility with older Steamworks SDK that some games are still built with.

From https://github.com/anyc/steam-overlay/issues/206

> Steam creates symlink .steampath pointing to nonexistent .steam/sdk32/steam in $HOME every time it is run whereas it should be pointing to .steam/bin32/steam.

> Do not remove or alter this symlink, it exists and is intentionally broken to provide legacy steamworks compatibility as being tracked at ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux#5245.
> (~/.steam/sdk32/anything is what is needed)

So if you use **steam**! You probably don't want to remove this file!

## How to resolve it (an elegant way) ?

If you don't remember anything! You can just go `find in folder` > `node_modules`! And search for `Failed to compile`! Which generally you'll always remember!

Make sure to pick the second found element!

[image]

Know that you can too, simply open the file search pallet (CTRL + P)

Search for `devServerUtils`

[image]

And search again within the file!

[image]

That may be faster!

After this you set the break points as shown in the next image!

And start a debuger terminal!

Know that you need only the **breakpoint** on the **return statement**!

[image]

You can too use a **process.exit()**! But i prefere the usage of the debugger! As it's cleaner and simple!

**Here how you start a javascript debug terminal!**

[image]

Run `npm start`! in that debugger terminal!

[image]

**The excution will automatically stop at the breakpoint**! And you'll be able **to read easily and simply see what the problem is**!

[image]

Know that once it's done once! You can later whenever needed, to just start a **javascript debug terminal**! And you'll have it works! As your break point will still there!

No knowledge is required to do so!

Still if not familiar with the debugger! And want to get to know it better!

You can check the debugger auto attach for nodejs processes and javascript debug terminal [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging)

Also [debugging in general](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging)

Comment: Fabulous answer! Great contribution to community!

Answer (score 12):

In my case, it was because of a missing package in package.json.

`yarn start` or `npm run start` didn't help me find the missing package. To find the missing one, try running the build command (`yarn build`), build will exit with the error details as below.

[image]

As the above screenshot says, there was a missing package (in my case `react-dnd-html5-backend`).

Answer (score 5):

This issue is caused because of some missing dependencies. The dependencies which were missing were not listed in the `package.json`, but was being used in the project.
You can see the error for a split second in the console before it clears. I had to record my screen and see it in slow-mo to find what was missing and installed it.

Comment: thanks I had to do the same! it clear too quick!

Answer (score 1):

Some package is missing. In my case it was @reduxjs/toolkit.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30299720)

Answer (score 0):

After downgrading node-sass to version 4, restart your development server.

Comment: You wont believe how many times this has happened to me

Comment: I am still getting the error. Downgrading is just changing the package.json file to ```"node-sass": "^4.0.0",``` right?

Comment: Yah. I tried to replicate your error but it did not work

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to check out your imports! I'm using VS code and got the very same issue because instead of doing

```js
import {useHistory} from 'react-router-dom'

// I did (well, actually vscode did it by performing incorrect autoimport)
import {useHistory} from 'react-router'
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved looking at this log, npm clears screen and lost all this info.

```
npm start > log.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

#### In my case, it helped running `yarn install` before `yarn start`.